# Launch a packaged UWP deployed to store using powershell scripts

Tags: powershell, uwp

I have a packaged UWP app that should be deployed to the store.
I have added **appcenter-post-build.ps1** at the solution level which contains the script to launch this app.
I deployed to the store and installed it from the store but auto-launch after installation is not working.
To make sure our script is working we have also written a script to send an email before the auto-launch script.
The email script itself is not working making us assume our script is not being read.
Is there any other way to launch the UWP app after installation from the store?

Comment: Currently, it’s not supported to auto-launch a UWP app after installation. If you want the feature, you could go to the **Feedback Hub** and submit a feature request.

Comment: Thank you, 
So can you please confirm if we can launch our UWP app from the windows service?